# Access custom Mixin's method from view - DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, mixins

I have custom mixin, which has a method with headers and fields parameter:

```
class CustomMixin:

     @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
     def do-method(self,request,params):
             //some stuff here
```

also I have view set:

```
class ModulViewSet(ModelViewSet,CustomMixin):
       //some stuff here
```

I'm interested how to pass 'params' parameter to do-method in ModulViewSet

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your View is inheriting from CustomMixin then you can just call the method like every other class method

Comment: I should create method in ModulViewSet which will call CustomMixin-s do-method method, right? Should I use @action decorator in CustomMixin or in ModulViewSet?

Comment: No. You can just call `do_method` on ModulViewSet. ModuleViewSet inherited this method from CustomMixin. Try it